# "Method 'invites.insert' not found [404]" but a console.log in the method is triggered

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

I'm pretty far on my first Meteor/React app, and I love the platform. I've implemented chat and playlists successfully, both of which make all sorts of calls to Meteor.methods, but this is the first time I've hit this error. The strange thing is a console.log in the method that's being called before the error is shown:

```
invites.js:11 token: ZTrTeovTFjdemQGF //console.log in method
playlist-details.js:70 errorClass {error: 404, reason: "Method 'invites.insert' not found", details: undefined, message: "Method 'invites.insert' not found [404]", errorType: "Meteor.Error"}
```

The method is in `/imports/collections/invites.js`, which I'm importing on the client in `/client/components/playlist-details.js`.

invites.js:

```
Meteor.methods({
    'invites.insert': function(data) {

        // generate token
        let token = randtoken.generate(16);
        console.log('token: ' + token);

        // some code here

        return Invites.insert({
            // data to insert
        });
    }
});

export const Invites = new Mongo.Collection('invites');
```

playlist-details.js

```
import { Invites } from '../../imports/collections/invites';

class PlaylistDetails extends React.Component {

    handleInviteClick() {

        // some code

        Meteor.call('invites.insert', data, (error) => { 
            if (error) { 
                console.log(error);
                this.props.store.systemMessage = {
                    type: 'error',
                    text: error.message
                }
            }
            else {
                this.props.store.systemMessage = {
                    type: 'confirmed',
                    text: `Invitation sent to ${data.inviteeEmail}`
                }
                this.refs.friendsQuery.value = '';
            }
        });
    }    
}
```

Comment: I think I saw this in an earlier SO question and the solution was to avoid naming the method with a dot. i.e. just use `'insertInvites'` instead of `'invites.insert'`

Comment: @MichelFloyd No luck, still get the error. Which makes sense, since all of the other methods are named with a dot, like `'playlists.insert'` and `'chats.insert'`. And all of those work fine.

Comment: hmmm. Is it possible this method is only available on the client and not on the server as well? i.e. it's being called correctly on the client but when latency compensation tries to call the server version it can't find it?

Comment: I was thinking something similar, essentially an async issue, but that doesn't make any sense since all other methods are working properly, and those methods are in the same folder as this one: `/imports/collections`

Comment: But is this method being imported into your server main.js?

Comment: No, only to the client right now, specifically `playlist-detail.js`, the second bit of code in my post. I'm not even sure if I need to import it to call it, since it works that way in another file.